# Add labels to a map plot

Tags: r, plot, shapefile

I am trying to add labels in a map plot using R.
I need to put a which condition to the labels. Have tried multiple options but to no avail.

```
png(filename="D:\\dm analysis3.png", width=959, height=593)
plot(zip,col=ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Super Top",'Dark Green',
                      ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Top Performer",'Light Green',
                    ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Average Performer",'Yellow',
                           ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Poor Performer",'Red',
                                  ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero returns",'Dark Red',
                                         'Grey'))))),
     border=ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Super Top",'Dark Green',
                   ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Top Performer",'Light Green',
                          ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Average Performer",'Yellow',
                                 ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Poor Performer",'Red',
                                        ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero returns",'Dark Red',
                                               'Grey'))))),
     bty="n")

with(subset(zip@data,zip@data$flag=="Y"),
     text(zip@data,labels=as.character(zip@data$code)))

map('state', plot = TRUE, fill = FALSE,add=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Can anyone tell me how to print labels, i am unable to do so

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare your vector of colors *before* you call the `plot` command. When inside the `plot` command, the parameter given to the `col` option is evaluated beforehand, with no such reasoning as "ok, now I'm plotting the n'th point, so let's *now* calcluate what is the n'th color, according to the current index in `zip`".

**EDIT**: I can see I may have answered too promptly, and off-side. What exactly is your issue? Does it concern what you feed the `col` option with? The `border` option? Or the things given to the `text` command later on?

Comment: I need a text label, which labels a particular value in each market im using....I mangaed to do it using a dummy dataset with geo-coordinates though...any better method would be much appreciated